# MySQL Apelidos no Inner Join

Tags: mysql

Tentei fazer esta junção interna no SQL para ligar duas tabelas no meu relatório.

O que eu estaria fazendo de errado, por que esta dando "Coluna ffccf desconhecida", mesmo eu apelidando a coluna?

Segue o código:

```
SELECT finafim.ccf as ffccf, finafim.impcaixa, finafim.numcup, finafim.vlfina, finafim.descfina,
       tabc470.ccf as t4ccf, tabc470.NSerie, tabc470.numcupom
FROM finafim
INNER JOIN tabc470
ON (finafim.numcup = tabc470.numcupom)
AND (finafim.ccf = tabc470.ccf)
AND (finafim.impcaixa = tabc470.NSerie)
WHERE ffccf= :ppccf AND numcup= :ppcoo AND impcaixa= :ppecf //Detalhes de parâmetros para igualar valores.
AND dtcomp BETWEEN "2014/03/01" AND "2014/05/01"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ff.ccf AS ffccf, ff.numcup, ff.impcaixa, t46.ccf AS t46ccf, t46.numcupom, t46.NSerie 
FROM finafim AS ff INNER JOIN tabc470 AS t46 
ON (ff.numcup = t46.numcupom) AND (ff.ccf = t46.ccf) AND (ff.impcaixa = t46.NSerie)
WHERE ff.ccf= :ppccf AND numcup= :ppcoo AND impcaixa= :ppecf //Detalhes de parâmetros para igualar valores. 
AND dtcomp BETWEEN "2014/03/01" AND "2014/05/01"
```

Segue o código correto...
Ele apenas aponta para a coluna exatamente como disse o Omni, nessas 3 condições.
Eu estava apontando ele dentro do Where, aonde não é viável, e nem permitido.

**Desculpem-me a falta de organização, é que minha empresa bloqueou vários sites de fóruns, e não estou conseguindo  organizar meu post direito.**

Comment: De fato eu consegui resolver o problema com isso, eu apenas removi algumas colunas que que eu não necessitava. E resolveu o problema, ou seja, eu apenas selecionei o que eu iria utilizar.

Answer (score 9):

Só pode usar referenciar colunas pelos seus `apelidos` (`alias`) nas seguintes cláusulas:

- GROUP BY
- ORDER BY
- HAVING

([Documentação MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html))

Portanto no seu caso a sua query teria de referenciar as colunas directamente no `WHERE` em vez de usar os `apelidos`.

Comment: count, sum, avg também

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi pode dar `apelidos` aos resultados das funções de agregação, mas não pode referenciar colunas pelos seus `apelidos` dentro das funções.

Comment: mas caso você de um select count(tabela), você vai precisar apelidar para conseguir retirar o valor, no caso é válido então também.

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi não precisa de apelidar o `count(...)` para retirar o valor (nesta caso o resultado iria aparecer count(...)) ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/25641))