# Como fazer inner join em mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo 2 tabelas no meu banco, Categorias e Automovéis. A tabela categorias possui uma PK ID_categoria e Nome. Já Automóveis possui uma PK ID_automoveis e as demais colunas que compoem essa tabela INCLUINDO a FK ID_Categoria como podem ver na imagem a baixo:
[image: Tabela automoveisqui]

Eu estou iniciando meus estudos em bancos de dados com mysql mas estou com muitas dificuldades em modelos relacionais e inner join. Se estiver algo errado eu posso alterar também!

Esse banco é manipulado por um sistema em PHP.

Comment: INNER JOIN é uma consulta pesada, so usada quando quer mesmo os registos todos da outra tabela correspondente.

Comment: Não devemos usar funções da extensão "mysql" pelo seu desenvolvimento ter sido descontinuado.Já que esta iniciando seus estudos sugiro começar com mysqli ou PDO.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8319/64969

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17522/64969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente isso amigo:

```
select
    *
from
    categorias c
inner join
    automoveis a
on a.ID_Categoria = c.ID_categoria
```

Comment: Excelente, deu certo, no caso agora é só eu listar em meu código. Agora se eu quiser fazer uma inserção no banco é só eu cadastrar a categoria via ID né.. bom agora consigo daqui! Obrigado mesmo @Rick

Answer (score 4):

A sua base de dados não está normalizada. Primeiramente, normalizaria a BD, criando assim as tabelas:

- Marca;
- Modelo;
- Cor;
- Categoria;
- Automóvel;

Após isso, pensaria em fazer as consultas, onde pode utilizar diferentes joins:

> INNER JOIN ou JOIN só: Retorna registros que têm valores 
>   correspondentes em ambas as tabelas;
>
> LEFT JOIN: retorna todos os registros da tabela à esquerda e os
>   registros correspondentes da tabela direita;
>
> RIGHT JOIN: retornar todos os registros da tabela direita e os
>   registros Correspondentes da tabela da esquerda;
>
> FULL (OUTER) JOIN: Retorna todos os registros quando há uma
>   correspondência na tabela esquerda ou direita

Comment: Sim, eu fiz este primeiro como teste. Como não estou com muito tempo decidi fazer a gambiara. Não é nada profissional que vai exigir 100% de correção. Mas sua ideia foi muito boa, levarei como sugestão. Muito obrigado!