# Como substituir dados com php mysql EX:

Tags: php

Tenho um uma tabela com todos os estados com uma coluna de ID DO ESTADO, E uma do nome do estado certo. Quando o usuário cadastra vai o numero do estado com o cadastro dele, ai preciso fazer uma consulta por exemplo se no cadastro do usuario ta escrito que o id do estado é 10, ai faz a consulta de qual o nome do estado esta com o id numero 10 e exibe o nome

Estou com o código assim, não adicionei o esquema que citei acima ainda!

```
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "joao", "123", "final");
    $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM c_clientes INNER JOIN c_clientes_enderecos ON c_clientes_enderecos.cliente_id = c_clientes.cliente_id;");
        while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
            echo
            "<tr>" . "<td>" . $row['cliente_id']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['cliente_nome']. " " . $row['cliente_sobrenome']). "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_nome_mae']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_email']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_telefone']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_celular']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_cpf']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_rg']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_nascimento_mae']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_status']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_data_emprego']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['usuario_id']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_mae_estado_id']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['regiao_id']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cliente_habilitado_regiao']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['endereco_id']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['endereco_cep']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['endereco_rua']). "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['endereco_numero']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['endereco_complemento']. "</td>" .
            "<td>" . $row['cidade_id']. "</td>" . 
            "<td>" . $row['estado_id']. "</td>" . //Aqui vem o id quero 
            //transformar no nome!
            "<td>" . $row['c_clientes_enderecos']. "</td>" . "</tr>"

            ;
        }
```

Comment: Esclareça melhor a sua dúvida, ela relacionada ao php? Ou à consulta no banco de dados? Inclua o seu código.

Comment: Não tenho um codigo, mas é para substituir o ID pelo nome na consulta dai

Comment: E qual é o banco de dados, nome e estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: Eu tenho o ID 1 por ex, e no cadastro do cliente ta o estado 1, como faço para substituir pelo nome

Comment: Estrutura http://prntscr.com/jawhn2

Comment: Se o nome do estado está em outra tabela, vc tem que fazer um JOIN

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jawi9m

Comment: Ja estão interligadas

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer inner join em mysql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208941/como-fazer-inner-join-em-mysql)

Comment: Veja a pergunta acima que vc deve conseguir.

Comment: mas preciso substituir o numero pelo nome

Comment: blz vou tentar! qualquer coisa aviso aqui se deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você tem que fazer um join, não é uma substituição e sim trazer os dados que pertence aquela determina região, exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id as usuarioID, u.nome, e.id as estadoID, e.uf from usuario as u 
inner join estado as e
on e.id = u.estadoId
where u.id = 1";

$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=local;dbname=teste', 'root', '');
$consulta = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$consulta->execute();

$dados = $consulta->fetchAll();

foreach($dados as $dado) {
   echo $dado;
}
```

Eu não testei esse código, mas tenho certeza que vai funcionar, fiz na mão aqui agora. Por favor, teste, se retornar algum erro me fale para que eu possa ajeitar. Lembrando que você deve substituir os dados de conexão e os das consultas.

Comment: Não uso pdo meu código esta assim!