# Busca e exibição de resultados 2 tabelas mysqli/php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Queria fazer uma busca em 2 tabelas (noticias e fotos) e depois exibir os resultados dessa consulta abaixo. Porém os campos que tenho em cada tabela são diferentes e não estou conseguindo elaborar uma forma de exibir os resultados por causa disso.

Campos da tabela notícias:
Titulo, foto, descrição, conteudo, data

Campos da tabela fotos:
Titulo, foto, data, local

Ex:

1. Pesquiso o termo "teste"...
2. Consulta nas duas tabelas e traz todos os resultados encontrados.

O resultado da busca queria parecido com a imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: O layout da imagem é apenas um exemplo, o que não estou conseguindo fazer é o codigo que gere o resultado. Se fosse o resultado de uma tabela só exibindo resultados apenas dela eu consigo fazer, mas exibindo resultados de 2 tabelas juntas e mesclados não consegui.

Comment: O que você tem de código até agora?

Comment: Na verdade nada. Mas vou postar como uso para exibir resultados de uma tabela.

Comment: De uma lida em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208941/como-fazer-inner-join-em-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa equiparar os campos das duas tabelas, assim a quantidade e nome das colunas retornadas serão iguais.

```
SELECT `titulo`, `foto`, `descricao`, `conteudo`, `data`, '' as `local`
FROM `noticia` WHERE [sua pesquisa]
UNION
SELECT `titulo`, `foto`, '' as `descricao`, '' as `conteudo`, `data`, `local`
FROM `fotos` WHERE [sua pesquisa];
```

E quando for exibir você valida se o campo não é vazio para ser exibido.

```
if (isset($query['campo']) && !empty($query['campo'])) {
     echo $query['campo'];
}
```

Comment: Dei +1 na resposta pq ela é correta, mas só uma observação: os nomes não precisam ser iguais no UNION, você pode selecionar por posição dos campos também, tanto em SQL quanto em PHP. (usando numeros em vez de nomes no SQL, e no PHP pegando o array numérico em vez de associativo)

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou corretamente ao que precisava. Muito Obrigado